# Logic games using TeX

Tags: puzzle, logicpuzzle

On my way to learn how to use LaTeX, I came across the `logicpuzzle` package and I found it really impressing how you can really generate all kinds of grids without including any picture.

For instance :

[image]
[image]
[image]

So I jumped happily in the source code [right here](https://bitbucket.org/kleberj/logicpuzzle/src/68f43e05896254cd6ca64c072f2b2d6952c56d48/Releases/logicpuzzle_v2.4.zip?at=master) (everything seems to be located in logicpuzzle.sty) and what I came across seems so obscure to me that I haven't learned a single thing.

Where or how can you learn to do such advanced things in LaTeX ? Or, at least, how is this more **basically** done ?

Comment: `Where or how can you learn to do such advanced things in LaTeX ?`  Keep visiting this site.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Okay, jumping on the horse as author of `logicpuzzle.sty`.

As David wrote, `logicpuzzle.sty` heavily uses `TikZ`. So you need to undestand at least the basics of `TikZ`.

The core part of `logicpuzzle` are the puzzle environments like `magnets` in one of your pictures above:

```
\begin{magnets}
...
\end{magnets}
```

This will always draw the basic grid. See the documentation (`texdoc logicpuzzle`) and take a look at the section about rolling out your own logic puzzle.

Then there are always puzzle related commands to fill the grid, which always uses `TikZ` for graphical objects plus some standard `LaTeX` ,e.g. the commands for filling rows.

The basic idea is that the grid spans from `(1,1)` to `(columns+1,rows+1)` (in `TikZ` coordinates). With grid cell `(1,1)` being the bottom left corner and grid cell `(columns,rows)` being the top right corner.
Placeing a mine (`\Mine`) in grid cell `(2,2)` for a mine sweeper puzzle, means placing a `Tikz` node in the center of grid cell `(2,2)`, which is `(2.5,2.5)` in coordinates. In the end, you put the graphical object defined in `\Mine -> \LP@Mine` into the node. That's exactly what e.g. `\setcell{2}{2}{\Mine}` does.

If you want to try to understand what's going on, my advice would be:

1. read 'Rollling out your own logic puzzle'
2. Take a look at an example and try to understand one macro after the other
3. For (2.) you will need to understand the basics of `TikZ`

I'm afraid this will not be easy! ;-)

At the moment, I'm transfering the documentation into `.dtx` (a documented source file). It's not finished and will not describe every single detail. You need to understand `TikZ`. So you read `TikZ`, `TikZ` and `TikZ`! ;-)
If you contact me, I can send you a PDF with the (so far) documented source code.

If you find a way to do it much easier, please contact me! ;-)

Comment: As for reading TikZ, it's [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) is (for lack of a better word) *renowned*, but the [minimal introduction](http://cremeronline.com/LaTeX/minimaltikz.pdf) isn't too shabby, either.

Comment: Well, thank you for your advices, I'll try to apply them to understand `logicpuzzle`. And thanks also for this awesome `.sty`, it will be really useful to me !

Comment: +1 even though you got the tick instead of me:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Well, home field advantage! ;-)

Comment: @Skydreamer See my latest edit. I think this will help you to understand the basic idea how the grids are drawn and filled!

Comment: @Josef Thank you for the edit, I think it will help, I've already taken a look at TikZ documentation.

Comment: @Skydreamer Rethinking the situation it might be better to start with https://bitbucket.org/kleberj/logicpuzzle/downloads/battleship_v1.2.zip! It's only the `battleship` puzzle and much less code. Climb the dragon afterwards. ;-)

Comment: @Josef I finally understood every single line of the `battleship` package. Now it's done, it's no more a mystery at all to me. So thanks for all your tips and help.

Answer (score 8):

The code is in texlive (at least) so most people won't need to download the zip file you link to.

The heart of it is

```
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.07*\LP@scale]%
    \draw[fill=brown!95!black!95,line width=.1pt*\LP@scale]%
      (.75,-1) .. controls (.5,.5) and   (.5,3) .. (0.5,4) --%
      (-0.5,4) .. controls (-.5,3) and (-.5,.5) .. (-.75,-1);%
    \shade[top color=green!50!black!60,draw=black,line width=.1pt*\LP@scale,bottom color=green!50!black]%
      (0,10) .. controls  (0,8)     and (1,7)    .. (1.5,7)%
```

....

As the environment name suggests this is TikZ, a drawing package for TeX. Tikz has a very extensive manual (`texdoc tikz` should show it) or you can browse the questions tagged [tikz-pgf](/questions/tagged/tikz-pgf) on this site, which is, by some margin the most common tag for questions.