# How would one create Bridges (Hasi) puzzle in LaTeX without installing logicpuzzle.sty file?

Tags: overleaf, logicpuzzle

I'm trying to create a bridge puzzle for my Homework assignment as shown [here](https://bitbucket.org/kleberj/logicpuzzle/wiki/Bridges) without installing logicpuzzle.sty file for my computer.  What I really want to do is to use Tikz to create that type of puzzle since I am using Write Latex site to create my documents.

Any advices or approaches?

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? You could extract the relevant portions of code from `logicpuzzle` and include it directly in your preamble, using `\makeatletter ... \makeatother` if appropriate. Since the package uses `tikz` anyway, that would fit your requirements.

Comment: Note that the `logicpuzzle` package allows to draw some puzzles. But these puzzles are logic iff _you_ are logic. In other words, with `logicpuzzle`, you can draw illogic puzzles... ;-)

Comment: @NasuSama see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128335/logic-games-using-tex/128357#128357; It explains the basic idea behind `logicpuzzle.sty`

Comment: @PaulGaborit You can use `\section`+ to write some crazy stuff! ;-)